# Anderson darling test results are similar for multiple variables

Tags: normal-distribution, anderson-darling-test

I performed the Anderson darling test from scipy.stats on multiple different variables but the test is outputting similar critical values for all the varaibles. Only the test statistics values are different. I hope someone can explain this.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{critical values at predefined significance} & \text{statisitics} \\ \hline
\text{significance boundaries} &  1, 2,5,10,15 &\\ \hline
\text{Var 1_critical values} & 1.09, 0.91,0.78,0.65,0.57 & 417.6\\ \hline
\text{Var 2_critical values} & 1.09, 0.91,0.78,0.65,0.57 & 282.6\\ \hline
\text{Var 3_critical values} & 1.09, 0.91,0.78,0.65,0.57 & 106.811 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Are your sample sizes the same?  If so, ...

Comment: yes, every variable has the same size.

Comment: With the same sample size, the critical values will be the same too.  At the 1% level of significance and your sample size, the critical value is 1.09; if the test statistic is greater than 1.09, the test result is significant at the 99% level of confidence.